# Did the modern British accent originate from a speech impediment?

Tags: british-english, rhoticity, received-pronunciation

I have heard a theory that the modern British pronunciation (as compared, for example, to American pronunciation) started when somebody in the monarchy had a speech impediment (perhaps rhotacism) and, rather than humiliate the person, aristocrats adopted the same affectation, and it developed and persisted from there.

Is there any truth or substance to this theory?  Or is there evidence to debunk it?

Comment: What are you thuggethting, thir?

Comment: I've never heard of it.  Where did you hear it? Do you have any evidence?

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: I don't remember where or when I heard that.  The only evidence I have is that received pronunciation sounds to Americans like an affectation to conceal speech impediments ;)

Comment: Interesting. I suppose it's possible. It sounds like a research project. Good luck! ;-)

Comment: The close-voter doth protest too much, methinks.

Comment: Sounds like as much of an urban legend as the idea that Spaniards have a "lisp" because of imitating some king with a speech impediment. (BTW, Castillian Spanish actually distinguishes between the "th" and "s" sounds, so a person with a lisp still wouldn't be able to pronounce some words correctly).

Comment: @sumelic - and that has been confirmed as a myth?  If so, how (or where)?  The same reasoning may inform this question.

Comment: I believe I once heard this, maybe 30-40 years ago.  It's plausible, except that one would have to believe there would be a significant historical record -- not the type of thing one could bury for centuries.  (Makes a good myth, though.)

Comment: @feetwet: well, one strong piece of circumstantial evidence that I mentioned above is that the standard form of Castillian Spanish cannot be pronounced  correctly by a lisper (someone who pronounces all their "s"s as "th"s) because it has a distinction between the "s" and "th" sound, just like English. The same reasoning doesn't apply directly to the British question.

Comment: Lack of evidence for the theory is all the evidence needed to debunk it: The burden of proof is on the theory, not on disproving it.

Comment: It is certainly true that "the Kings English" got yanked back and forth multiple times, as various French and German influences came and went in the king's court.  But the nature of these transitions is pretty well known, and (based on my admittedly understanding of the individual influences) it seems unlikely that one of the transitions could account for the whole "R" business.

Comment: @HotLicks Read the linked material in [this comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264110/did-the-modern-british-accent-originate-from-a-speech-impediment/264122?noredirect=1#comment580770_264122).

Comment: @tchrist - Alas, while I read English fairly well, I can't read Greek at all.

Answer (score 7):

The king who is known to have had a speech impediment was King George VI, father to the present Queen, who reigned from 1936 to 1952. The matter of his speech impediment was dramatised in the film *The King's Speech* (2010) written by David Seidler, in which Colin Firth plays the part of the King. This clearly has nothing to do with the formation of the Received Pronunciation which was already long established before George VI was born.

I have heard it said, but have never read anything about the matter, that one of the earlier Georges, possibly George II (reigned 1727 - 1760), who had difficulty with English (he had been born a German, and German was his first language) had rather quaint ways of saying things. Some of his more idiosyncratic expressions were affected by courtiers and other sycophants - which may explain a few surviving odd-sounding British expressions such as *What ho* and *Hey what*.

**But it would be ridiculous to suppose that the entire system of Received Pronunciation could have become established in that way**.

**Note on *rhotacism***

***Rhotacism*** is a speech impediment involving difficulty in pronouncing the letter r. It probably has nothing whatever to do with the *rhotic r* sound.

Most regional dialects in Britain do not sound the *rhotic* r. It is however a feature of the various West Country accents, from Cornwall in the south-west to Hampshire and Berkshire in the east. One theory holds that it is the origin of the North American rhotic r.

Comment: Both George I and George II are known to have spoken very bad English, if at all, much prefering German (and Germany, for that matter). In the 18th century, the rhotic r was still common in the entire south of England, not just the West Country, if memory serves.

Comment: @JoostKiefte You do make the most sweeping statements. How exactly do you know where the rhotic r was used in southern England in the 18th century? Where have you read that? Are you suggesting that Londoners spoke with a rhotic r? I have read fairly extensively the writings of Professor Peter Trudgill the leading authority on the East Anglian dialects, and I have never picked up any idea from him that the rhotic r ever extended any further than the counties I mentioned.

Comment: @JoostKiefte And you signally fail to say how you know about how people spoke in 18th century England. I trust you do not have tape recordings!

Comment: We do know that the /r/ was originally present historically: see [Rhoticity in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhoticity_in_English). Its loss did not become posh and widespread until (shortly) after the severing of ties.

Comment: @WS2: that would go for you too then, wouldn't it. You read the works of one prof and that's gospel to you then? Not a very scientific way of going about it. See tchrist's comment......

Comment: @Joost Kiefte: It is well documented that the original English settlers of Massachusetts, Puritans who came over in the first half of the 17th century, mainly from the East and Southeast of England, generally did not have a rhotic r (although I believe the prestigious London accent did at the time). So maybe not the entire South of England, depending on what you define as the South

Comment: @petershor. Correct, London's rhoticism is still contentious. It will ever remain so, I'm afraid. Not sure that really matters, anyhow.

Comment: @PeterShor Certainly no vestiges of rhotic r remain in British elite accents (so far as I'm aware). Surely if it had been part of a prestigious accent, something would still be apparent today? I mean, who were these posh London rhotics?

Comment: @tchrist It is my understanding that 18th century elites largely spoke what today we think of as regional accents. Presumably those from areas where the rhotic r was prominent also spoke in that way. I believe it to have been the elite Public Schools, and places like the Royal Military Academy, Sandhurst which promoted a common accent based more on social class/education than on region.

Comment: All English was originally rhotic. Some regions have lost that. Others have preserved it. The OP posits a somewhat silly old wives' tale to explain how this came to be lost. It's more of "Just So" story than anything.

Comment: @tchrist How do we know that "all English was rhotic"? Who should I be reading on this subject?

Comment: Chaucer will do. Middle English orthography was phonetic, just as Old English's was. They did not write letters they did not say; that came later.

Comment: @tchrist, WS2: This is [nifty](https://books.google.com/books?id=TAOrBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA127&dq=nonrhotic+history&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwA2oVChMIlKONyoGJxwIVUqyACh3_HAb-#v=onepage&q=R-related&f=false), 115 ff. De-rhoticization is a very long and complex process. Most authorities seem to agree that non-rhotic coda r didn't percolate into the prestige dialect until the end of the 18th century. The US nonrhotic dialects are precisely those which were major seaports and exposed to British prestige English in the first half of the 19th century: Boston, New York, and the Tidewater.

Comment: And WS2: It looks to me like your piece of the country was the bellwether.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks! That’s quite a nice find — and definitely a more compelling tale of “How the R was lost” than the Just-So story posted in the question.  It’s also rather longer:  I read pages 115–132 before I came back to thank you. :)

Comment: @StoneyB That is not something I am going to grasp in five minutes - but I will give it a try. I am just wondering where and exactly what you mean when you say "your piece of the country was the bellwether"

Comment: NMF, but I get the impression from browsing around that r-dropping arose in East Anglia by the 15th century and spread from there.

Comment: @StoneyB Is there a book I can read where it tells me all this - a sort of beginner's guide to the history of the English language? The only thing I have read so far is Bryson's *Mother Tongue* which according to one professional on this site is almost worse than useless.

Comment: My textbook 50 years ago was the 2nd edition of Baugh; it's now in its sixth edition, 2012. [Here](http://www.amazon.com/History-English-Language-6th/dp/0205229395/ref=mt_hardcover?_encoding=UTF8&me=)'s the Amazon listing, which has links to similar works.

Comment: @StoneyB Thanks. I see that Amazon US is asking $155; but Amazon UK has a paperback version for £25. I'll see if my University library has a copy. Thanks very much.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26784/discussion-on-answer-by-ws2-did-the-modern-british-accent-originate-from-a-speec).

Answer (score 4):

It strikes me as quite unlikely. American English and British English sounded much alike until 1783, and from then on they may have branched away from each other.

George III, on the throne between 1760 and 1820, suffered from a progressive mental condition but is not known to have had a speech impediment. The two sons who followed him on the throne, George IV and William IV, were embarrassments in various ways, but not voice-wise. Their respective reigns may not have lasted long enough to influence a whole nation's speech. Victoria, who ascended the throne after William IV, had a German accent.

The king most people might have felt vicariously ashamed for would have been George VI, the famous stammerer and subject of the film *The King's Speech*. I have as yet to come across people who would affect a stammer so as not to upstage His Majesty.

Comment: Your answer begins with the ridiculous and ends with the undiplomatic. It is rare that I exercise a down vote but on this occasion I feel moved to do so. It is quite absurd to say that "British and American sounded much the same until after 1783". You may know that Britain is a country of hugely divergent regional accents. The idea that Americans and all these regional British once spoke in the same way is patently ridiculous. There are, however, similarities between American English and some West Country and Irish accents. (continued)

Comment: Then, surely, you must also find the question ridiculous because there is no British accent. As it is, my answer is as generalising as the question and as such fits the bill.

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that early colonists in North America will have spoken with the same accents from whence they came. Perhaps that is what Joost meant.

Comment: I have never met anyone who felt "vicariously ashamed" of George VI. Most people were sympathetic toward him, and admired the way that he persevered with his speech. A modest man, he remains a revered monarch who reigned throughout the course of the second world war. He and his family stayed in London throughout the course of the *blitz*, during which time Buckingham Palace was hit by German bombs. He and the Queen refused to go to Canada, are said to have eaten the same food rations available to the public, and indicated that he intended to live and, if necessary, die in London.

Comment: ...but then that was long before the late 18th century. I would expect new accents to be evolving in the melting pot of cultures in North America well before 1783.

Comment: @WS2 I did not use the word 'might' for nothing.

Comment: I note that you are from the Netherlands. You may or may not know that your own Queen Wilhelmina and her family, arrived in Britain by ship in May 1940, as refugees from Nazi Germany. They were immediately taken in to Buckingham Palace where they received the hospitality of George VI and Queen Elizabeth for the duration of the war, until it was safe for them to return.

Comment: @avon your comment hits the nail on the head. I hazard the gues that the melting pot is more something of the 19th century?

Comment: @WS2 There's no need to condescend, there's a good chap.

Comment: @JoostKiefte I take your point about there being many and varied accents in America prior to 1783, and am prepared to change my assessment of your answer from *ridiculous* to *over-simplified*. But you need to bear in mind that in 1783 the settlement in the "thirteen colonies" was miniscule by comparison with today, and there had not been massive migration at that time.

Comment: @JoostKiefte I was not condescending. It was merely that I took exception to your suggestion that George VI was "the king most people might have felt vicariously ashamed for", particularly coming from a Dutchman!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26498/discussion-between-joost-kiefte-and-ws2).

Comment: "I hazard the gues that the melting pot is more something of the 19th century?" I think undoubtedly more so as time went on and colonies grew and merged. But New York especially would have been a melting pot of cultures from the outset (from being New Amsterdam)

Comment: Yes, New Amsterdam, or more precise, Manhattan, was the only melting pot. The other settlements did not allow other nationalities in and closely guarded their own cultural heritages. You might want to read Russel Shorto's excellent book "Island at the Centre of the World".